# How do I play this part?( New Divide Linkin Park)

Tags: guitar, notation, practice, tablature

How do I play this part (New Divide-Linkin Park)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The B (2nd fret "A" string, second line from bottom) needs to keep ringing out while you play the bottom two F#'s (2nd fret "E" string, bottom line).

Answer (score -2):

play with a pick and a finger (alternative ways -- with fingers or with  a pick strike) or better see on youtube and vimeo how an author did that... eyes can help your ears to cover a song correctly... almost all tabs do not reflect 100% an actual song...